# Can an independent daughter inherit like a son?

Tags: halacha, women, estates-inheritance

Normally* in halacha women do not inherit or aquire property and are extensions of their fathers, brothers, and husbands who, in exchange, are obligated to support them.

BUT in the case of the husband, the wife change the default arrangement and say "don't support me" and then she will personally keep any money she gets.

Can she make this arrangement with her father before he dies? If so, then seemingly there is no "obligation to support" for her brothers to inherit: does she receive a portion of the inheritance like her brothers?

Comment: Can you source your many claims in this question? (eg. the entire second paragraph, that adult single women don't acquire property, that the fiscal arrangement in the second paragraph can be applied to a father-daughter relationship)

Comment: The second paragraph is about a married woman. As for the third paragraph, that is part of the question!

Comment: Who is your comment directed at? I just asked for sources.

Comment: Zelophehad's daughters, anyone?

Comment: They had no brothers and they had to marry within their tribe.